# Why there is difference in path reference for node.js program hello.js?

Tags: node.js

In my earlier program, I had trouble in referencing hello.js file and run using node.js on windows. Please check this [How to run a hello.js file in Node.js on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows)

```
setTimeout(function() 
{
console.log('world!');
},2000);
console.log('hello');
```

When I was at work place I was able to run the above program using the following syntax:

```
c:\>node c:\abc\hello.js
```

But when I came home and tried using the same syntax, the same program **did not run**.  When I tried using the following syntax it worked.  **Why is this difference? Is this because of path variable or something else?**

```
C:\>C:/njs/node.exe C:/njs/hello.js
hello
world!
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in the second computer, node is **not on your PATH variable**.

Please check this by doing:

`echo %PATH%`

from the command line.

If so you need to modify `PATH` and add node binaries there, see this link:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: So even if the path points to node.exe in a different folder (not containing the hello.js), then also it is valid as long as it points to one node.exe.  Am I correct?

Comment: PATH should contain the folder that has `node.exe`, this is what let's you run `node` form any folder