# Search and replace with Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) like template file that needs to be parsed. e.g.

```
abc def ghijk{{ var1 }} lmno {{ var2 }} pq
rst={{ var3 }} uvwzyx
```

Variables like `{{ var1 }}` need to be replaced by a variable with the same name, which is already defined previous in the bash script, e.g `var1="foobar"`.

I am thinking of using `while read` and `awk` to accomplish this, but don't know what is the correct way to do string manipulation in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you expecting the awk to be able to handle things like partials and render blocks etc?  I think you're better off trying something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092641/how-to-run-debug-javascript-in-command-line) and using mustache.js in a local js file.

Comment: @n0741337 No, not that much, just simple variable substitution is enough. And for some reason, I cannot use third-party libraries but only pure bash/awk/sed.

Comment: Show your expected output along with how the mapping of var1, etc. are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export var1="duper"
export var2="tester"
export var3=1231
sed -e 's/{{ *\([^} ]*\) *}}/$\1/g' -e 's/^/echo "/' -e 's/$/"/' input | sh
```

*Gives:*

```
abc def ghijkduper lmno tester pq
rst=1231 uvwzyx
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! just FYI, since my data file may contain double quotes therefore I need to do an extra round of replace of `-e 's/"/\\"/g'`. Can you explain what does `[^} ]*` mean in your answer?

Comment: `[^} ]*` means any character except a `}` or a space.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an all awk version that requires a file of key=value pairs for the replacements.  If I make a `vars` file like:

```
 var1 =foobar
 var2 =elf
 var3 =monkey data
```

where I "cheated" and included the whitespaces associated with vars in your data file.  Then I made an executable awk file like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="="}
NR==FNR {vars[$1]=$2; next}

set_delims==0 {FS="[{][{]|[}][}]"; $0=$0; set_delims=1 }

{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf( "%s%s", ($i in vars) ? vars[$i] : $i, i==NF?"\n":"")
    }
}
```

If the executable awk file is called `awko` it can be run like `awko vars data`:

```
abc def ghijkfoobar lmno elf pq
rst=monkey data uvwzyx
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently and found this nice mustache implementation in bash: https://github.com/tests-always-included/mo

If you have all your variables already defined in the current bash context it's as simple as calling:

```
./mo template.file
```

With a slightly different usage it also supports other mustache features like partials or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a scalable manner (lots of macros to expand), you'll probably want to look into using a macro processor.  [GNU m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) springs to mind, though it only allows alphanumeric and `_` characters in macro names, so may be tricky for this particular task.

To get you started, you can use `sed` to do the replacements with this sed script (I called it mustache.sed):

```
s/{{ var1 }}/foobar/g
s/{{ var2 }}/bazbar/g
s/{{ var3 }}/quxbar/g
```

In use with your example:

```
$ sed -f mustache.sed mustache.txt
abc def ghijkfoobar lmno bazbar pq
rst=quxbar uvwzyx
$
```

You could put this sed script all on one sed command line, but I think using the script makes it more readable.