# How to execute a hello world javascript file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

I have `hello_world.js` file located on my computer at the following location -

```
C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working
```

It has the following code-

```
console.log("Hellow World");
```

I was reading a beginners tutorial [here](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#hello-world) and it says I should execute my javascript file through node.js. Now I have no idea what to do. How would I do this.

When I do this ...
[image]

I get nothing.
What should I be doing to run the hello world successfully. None of the tutorials seem to be showing what needs to be done.

I am very new to this so it is probably something that is very obvious to you guys.

Comment: There are so many postings available at SO on this , here is the one which I often refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows Review the answer posted by @kcbanner which exactly solves your problem .

Comment: What if I had to require a module, say like bluebird?

Comment: Syntax Error! This is not a valid "Hello World" program.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `Node.js command prompt`, then type in `node C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working\hello_world.js`

Comment: @missingno no he used the one with the green and white icon

Comment: I had the same problem, just did what you said thru the node.js cmd and all i get is nothing, empty line.

Comment: beautiful. i was just missing the `node` kw

Answer (score 21):

looks like you are in a node console already. you typed `node` which correctly started node (so your path is fine). Now you are telling node to interpret

```
node C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working\hello_world.js
```

as javascript which it doesn't like.

You should be able to type `console.log('hello world');` here and see it appear.

To run your file, quit out of the node interpreter (i think control-X, maybe control-C), and at your C:> prompt, THEN type

```
node C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working\hello_world.js
```

Alternately,

```
cd C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working\
node hello_world.js
```

Answer (score 3):

You have entered the node console, by typing `node` into a command prompt, and then tried to execute node from within itself. Just type `node c:\etc\...\` from the command prompt, not the node shell.

Press: [Start]->[Run]->[c][m][d]

And enter command: `node C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working\hello_world.js`

Alternatively, use sublime editor, and install a node js build system, and just open the file you want to run, and press the build shortcut, getting the output in the console.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open CMD.
2. Type "cd C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working" and hit Enter
3. Type "node hello_world.js" and hit Enter

This should work out !!
IMPORTANT: Dont type node before the point number 3.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these three easy steps:

- Go to your working directory

  ```
  C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working
  ```
- Open cmd there and type

  ```
  node hello_world
  ```
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Alternative.
Open Nodejs "The thing with a green icon".
Copy the code that you would like to be  executed from the file that you have

paste it in nodejs then press enter

nodejs understands js code so it will execute what you have written and output
hello world
undefined

What you have descripbed opens the file that you have and then executes it.

Answer (score -1):

Open Windows cmd and type

```
node C:\Users\Ankur\Downloads\NodeJS\working\hello_world.js
```

You should use node from system interpreter (bash/DOS cmd), what you are running is C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe without any arguments.