# node.js spits out nothing but three dots

Tags: node.js

I installed node.js on Windows machine and opened command prompt. When I tried "Hello World" examples the only output I'm getting is three dots:

```
node hello.js
...
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 7):

"node hello.js" is not valid javascript, so node repl ( Read-Evaluate-Print Loop ) assumes that error is because you are entering multi line javascript and indicates this with '...'. To exit multi line mode just enter '.' command.

As mentioned in first comment, this is common confusion (starting node.exe and entering 'node hello.js' in repl) - read linked answer first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  It looks like you're running the command correctly, what's the code in the js file?

Perhaps this link will help.
 [How to execute a hello world javascript file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206849/how-to-execute-a-hello-world-javascript-file-in-node-js)

Or maybe you wrote to output three periods :P