# node example.js and three dots, what's next?

Tags: node.js

Refering to the [homepage](http://nodejs.org//) and the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html), I installed node.js, created example.js and ran the script. But I got 3 dots (...) and nothing else. Where should I look?

```
> node example.js
...
```

Running this on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Do you mean the example node http server of "Hello World". `> node example.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/`? Is this?

Comment: @atupal I just updated my question. Thanks. Yes, I was expecting the console.log message, but it did not appear. Where should I put the example.js file? Even after specifying the full path D:/path/to/example.js it did not work.

Comment: maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows) is helpful. :)

Comment: You can type ".load example.js" in node REPL :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears that you have run `node.exe`, which opens a terminal, and have typed `node example.js` into that terminal.

So basically, you opened `node` in an interactive terminal, and then typed `node example.js`, so it is trying to run that as if it were JavaScript. It shows the three dots because that is not valid JavaScript code, and it is waiting for you to type more code that might make it valid.

You should be running `node.exe example.js` from a `cmd` prompt, where you'd see a prompt more like `C:\>`.