# Execute command without navigating to directory in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I have 2 directories on my windows.

1. C:/jenkins/workspace
2. D:/Projects/scripts/ (index.js file is in this directory)

Now, I want to execute command `node index.js --debug`.
I want to execute this command from `C:/jenkins/workspace` without navigating to `D:/Projects/scripts/`

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a hello.js file in Node.js on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6737824/1380680)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following into a batch file:

```
cd /d "D:\Projects\scripts\"
node index.js --debug
```

Comment: he said: "without navigating to `D:/Projects/scripts/`". Also you need `/d` with `cd` to change to another drive.

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks for answer. I don't know why windows command prompt works like that :\

Answer (score 3):

```
"D:/Projects/scripts/node" index.js --debug
```

the `"` are not really needed in this case, but it's a good habit tu use them, because they prevent from failures, if the path or filename contains spaces.

Comment: This is what answers the OP, not the accepted answer