# how can I open web application requiring node.js

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, bower

I must run micro-crawler https://github.com/WebMole/Micro-Crawler which is a crawler web application, that run with node.js.
I could not figure out how to open this app, I download node.js, and when I write install npm and install bower to the node.js command line nothing happened. Also I did not understand how to start web applicaion after installations

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the issue

- First, I install node.js, then move node.js folder to wampserver directory,
  and move the web sites files in the node.js directory
- Second, I go to the path where node.js is from command line, then enter "install npm" command
  line
- The error appeared in this phase for solving I create a npm
  folder in c:users/user_name_of_your_computer/app_data/roaming then I installed git and enter the directories of bin and cmd files of git to the system enviroments/path
- Third I enter the commands "bower install" and "npm install -g grunt-cli" from the comand. from the path of where node.js is

and the micro-crawler works

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute your .js file? You can do that with node.js cli thus:

path/to/your/file: node file.js

This is a good reference:
[How to run a hello.js file in Node.js on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows)

Comment: I tried this now there is a Gruntfile.js file and I ran it. But nothing happened.

Comment: Were you in the same directory as you the file you were trying to execute? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: http://imgur.com/uweOKgw       I put all micro-crawler files in node.js file, and put node files in wamp server www file

Comment: I meant screenshot of both working folder and commaind line interface. Furthermore, there's no need for what you did.