# I got a problem when I input any node cmd,

Tags: node.js

I got a problem when I input any npm cmd, it says

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584

Operating System: Windows 8 pro 64bit

What shall I do to solve this issue?[image]

Comment: Looks like your current directory doesn't contains the myfirst.js file. Please post the output of the dir command

Comment: I did not use dir command. Directly i goes to the file containing folder and opening the cmd prompt by right click with pressing shift button their.

Comment: can you list the contents of your directory?

Comment: Local Disk (C:)~ users~NUMAN ALI~myfirst.js    @nathan Wright

Comment: who can i do this (The file you have just created must be initiated by Node.js before any action can take place.)

Comment: To get help with your question, you need to add as much details as you can. You'll likely get no answer the way your post stands.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message of:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\NUMAN ALI\myfirst.js'

indicates that `Node` can't find your `myfirst.js` file to run within your current directory of: `C:\Users\NUMAN ALI`. Your `myfirst.js` file isn't located within this directory so  you need to *move into the correct directory containing this file, or alternatively create this file* in the current directory. Then you need to add your desired `JavaScript` within this file to run it.

With your comment of: "*The file you have just created must be initiated by Node.js before any action can take place*" I am going to assume you don't have this file in your current directory. Maybe you could try creating the file in a text editor, such as notepad at the very least on a Windows machine, and adding the `JavaScript` contents into this file. Then try re-running the file with a `node myfirst.js`. Check out this accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows) as I think this will help you out a lot. Also, for command line help for creating files, check out this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001359.htm).

Hopefully that helps!