# Nodejs won't execute my js file the way an author of a book says

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

Good morning, beginner here.

Im reading a book where the author tells me to run a command from the command line to execute a program made in js, source:https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html#h_TUzbi7lU/0

I've downloaded the lastest recommended version of nodejs (12.13.0 LTS), made the js file the book tells me to run (I made it in visualstudio because renaming a .txt file with the code to .js didn't do the job) and copy pasted it in the folder where the nodejs folder is, ran the command (ran several others that i thought would work as well) and i get this error:

[image: nodeterminal]

This other thread had a similar problem with a solution, while it might solve the problem of running the program, it doesn't run it in the way the author of the book im reading tells me to, [How to run a hello.js file in Node.js on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close this node terminal and start a new command prompt from the desired location and run "node hello.js" in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to SO.

You seem to have run `node` then `hello` in the node REPL, which is, of course an undefined variable.

Exit out of node and run `node hello.js`. This will use `node` to execute the code in the `hello.js` file if you are in the same folder/directory as it.

Comment: i did it this way and it ran the program, i still don't know why it wouldn't run the program when i use the command "$ node hello.js"