# Javascript Module error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test simple `export`  and `import`sample.

```
//file   a.js

export const a = 2
```

```
//file   b.js

import {a} from './a.js'


console.log(a);
```

But it show error

> import {a} from './a.js'
>
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I use vscode to test this.

> a.js and b.js is in the same folder.

I have no idea to this.

Comment: How do you load b.js ?
Is it from a web page in a browser?
Is it running server-side in node.js?

Comment: run in vscode node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on browser try @karma Blackshaw 's answer . If your are using node add       `"type": "module"` to your package.json . 
Or you can change extension of your .js files to .mjs and run with `--experimental modules` flag

a.mjs

```
//file   a.mjs

export const a = 2
```

b.mjs:

```
import {a} from './a.mjs'


console.log(a);
```

and run using :

```
node --experimental-modules b.mjs
```

[Read docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing the following:

When using ES6 modules from browser use .js extension in your files and in script tag add `type = "module"`

Comment: Is it possible to run javascript node.js in vscode? It still show same error.

I try your way in Chrome, it's work!

Comment: yes. You can open the command line in your current directory and type `node index.js` or whatever your filename is

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows) will give you a head start